# How does one add a typing to typings.json for Typescript in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript-typings, typescript1.8

I have to ask because this is driving me crazy.  I see the npm way of installing typings on Google, but [Angular2's tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) has one add a typings.json file then it added the typings folder and downloaded d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped automatically.  I tried this with jquery but it didn't download.  I also tried rebuilding the project, which I would expect the package.json to include the commands to add additional typings.

Here's my scripts from the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "typings": "typings",
  "postinstall": "typings install"
}
```

Here's the typings.json file I tried.  es6-shim and jasmine downloaded.

```
{  "ambientDependencies": {
   "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
   "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
   "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
}}
```

It's probably something simple like not having what appears to be a checksum after the hashtag.  Where would I find the correct checksum, or what command do I need to add to package.json to retrieve the typings upon compile, or what am I doing wrong?

[Here's another example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html) of adding a line to the typings.json file and then it installs the d.ts files for you.  Scroll down until you see **Manual Typings**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Make sure you have [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) installed
2. Open up your console of choice (e.g. command prompt or powershell)
3. Navigate to your project folder

**Using only npm** (TypeScript 2 and later):

4. `npm install --save @types/jquery`

   Done: See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) for more info.

**Using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)** (Typescript before v.2):

4. Make sure you have [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) installed, if not run `npm install typings --global`
5. Write `typings install dt~jquery --save --global`

   This should update your typings.json file and download the definition files.

   In the above example for typings, 'dt~' means that it should look for jquery in the [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) repository, the default is 'npm'. The syntax has changed slightly from version 0.x to 1.0, the flag `--global` was previously `--ambient`.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I'm trying to figure out how `"postinstall" : "typings install"` in the `package.json` file needs the `typings.json` entries formatted so that it does the same thing as this manual process.

Comment: Assuming `"postinstall": "typings install"` in package.json is the same as `npm install typings` above, does npm use `typings.json` to figure out what to go get?  Also, does it keep it up to date if you run `npm install typings` a second time?  Maybe we just need to add some command to `postinstall`?

Comment: This is what worked for me: "typings install dt~jquery --save --global". The "dt" defines the source repository, "--save" will add the definition to the typings.json file.

Comment: I can confirm that you must put dt~ before the library.Even if you try without dt~ , typings will guide you to use the correct name with verbose error messages.

Comment: Where to write these commands? I tried `powershell`. It did not work. I am using `VS 2015 Community`. It says `The term 'typings' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound. FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: @barnes Sounds like you didn't install typings properly. Did you do point 1 and 2?

Comment: @barnes Added clarifications to the instructions.

Comment: I haven't installed `npm`. I started `VS 2015 Comm` and followed a tutorial.

Comment: @barnes You have to have npm, typings is a npm package.

Comment: Thanks :). I am currently following you link and a few others. Will do as per your edits.

Answer (score 4):

I found that opening and resaving package.json once the typings.json file had been created triggered the typings to pull down. This is my current typings file:

```
{
    "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
        "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not run `typings install` which is what pulls down the files.

Comment: If you look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#typings

You can see that you still also need to add 

`"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install"
}`

to your `package.json`